# How to split a String with a pattern not with charaters in TCL

Tags: regex, shell, unix, scripting, tcl

Lets assume I have a variable called "giri" holding a string.

```
set giri "hello Manu hi how are you"
```

I want to split the variable `$giri` with a pattern `hi`. I tried split command and it is spiting with charters only

Please Help me with the essayist solution to split sting based on patterns

Comment: are you really interested in unix shell answers? Or just Tcl?

Comment: @glennjackman i am interested in tcl . I am trying to write a tcl proc

Comment: I was wondering why you chose all those tags.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
::textutil::split::splitx $giri hi
```

In the package [textutil::split](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html) (part of the tcllib)

`::textutil::split::splitx` uses a regexp, so be careful if you pass meta characters.

Comment: Splitting by a literal is easy: use `***=$theLiteral` for the RE…